# How to match any room description with regular expression in Mushclient

Tags: regex, lua, mud

I would like to generate a regular expression that matches with a room description like this:

```
My Room Description(enter, n, s, e and w)
My Room Description(enter, e, s, w and n)
My Room Description(s, w, e, n and enter)
My Room Description(n, e, w, s and enter)
```

The exit directions could be in different position but will always be the same amount (4) in this case.

This should *not* match:

```
My Room Description(n, up, e, w, s and enter)
```

because it has *5* exits (other than “enter”).

Comment: Would this do: `"^My Room Description\(.*?\)( or)?`? How many lines can there be that match this that aren't the one you want?

Comment: Its only this line, but it could be another with the same description but more exits: ex: My Room Description(n, e, w, s, enter and up), notice that this one has an extra exit: up. In this case, I would like to ignore the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
^My Room Description\((\w+(, | and )?){5}\)$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/StH3ZIZGsu1XTk).

——-

To allow optional leading text, such as `"HP:245 EP:245 >> "` as per your comment:

```
^[\w: >]*My Room Description\((\w+(, | and )?){5}\)$
```

Or more strict:

```
^([\w: ]* >> )?My Room Description\((\w+(, | and )?){5}\)$
```

This restricts the leading characters to only those you’ve provided as an example. To allow anything:

```
^.*My Room Description\((\w+(, | and )?){5}\)$
```

Comment: Slightly simpler: `^My Room Description\((\w+, ){3}[^,]*\)` - only three commas in a match

Comment: @Mark depends if you want to assert the syntax, or allow almost anything.

Comment: Sometimes my room description looks like this:
My Room Description(enter, n, s, e and w), and sometimes looks like this: HP:245 EP:245 >> My Room Description(enter, up, s, w and n). I am using this one for the second case: ^.*>> My Room Description\((\w+(, | and )?){5}\)$. Now, is there any way to match both description (with and without the HP:245 EP:245 >>)? Thanks!

Comment: @mark surround text with backticks to format as code (which retains escapes). I edited your comment above into add such backticks.